# Как убедится, что response body пустой?

Tags: rest

/*
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: an empty collection
  Actual:

*/

Надо проверить, что response body пустой. 
//import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.empty; не помог

какие еще есть варианты подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Оказалось все просто

assertThat().
body(equalTo(""));

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки пустого body, используют метод **Matchers.anything()**

*org.hamcrest.Matchers.anything;*

```
given().when()
        .get(request)
        .then().statusCode(200)
        .body(Matchers.anything());
```